# Cannot access layout elements using fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments

I had posted a similar question a couple of weeks ago, but my current issue is a bit different now. This is basically a repost but with update info. Here's my main activity. My spinner used to be null but now I seem to have it initializing but nothing is populating. I've spent quite a while on this, researched a lot of posts online for a solution and tried a number of fixes. Nothing has worked so far. Any ideas?

Also, ignore the date creation/sorting code. It's very messy, I already have a neater way of doing it but won't implement it until I have this part fixed.

**Note:** The id's are all correct in my layouts, I'm very sure that's not the problem.

```
public class RADIO_Live extends FragmentActivity {

    SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    ViewPager mViewPager;
    View fragviewLive;
    View fragviewPod;

    private int mYear, mMonth, mDay, cYear, cMonth, cDay;
    private TextView mCurrentDate;
    private TextView mSelectedDate;
    private TextView TextCurrentTime;
    private TextView TextTotalTime;

    boolean firstRUN = true;

    SeekBar Podseekbar;
    int myProgress = 0;
    int podMax = 0;
    int CurrentPosition = 0;

    boolean playerPODon = false;        // variable to keep track if live stream player and podcast player is on or off and if podacast player is paused
    boolean playerPODon1st = true;

    String mMonthName, cMonthName, cMonthFullName;
    String podFileTest, podPlayName, SelectedHour, SelectedDate = null;
    String showdate, HourShowText = null;

    String[] podDates = new String[14];
    String[] podDatesName = new String[14];
    int testDay = 0;
    int dayOfWeek;

    private final Handler UIhandler = new Handler();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three primary sections
        // of the app.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        //context.startService(serviceIntent);
        startService(new Intent(this, RADIO_Service.class));

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);
        fragviewPod = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.podcasts, null);

        // Capture the textview elements
        mCurrentDate = (TextView) fragviewPod.findViewById(R.id.currentdateDisplay);
        mSelectedDate = (TextView) fragviewPod.findViewById(R.id.selecteddateDisplay);

        TextTotalTime = (TextView) fragviewPod.findViewById(R.id.TotalTimeText);
        TextCurrentTime = (TextView) fragviewPod.findViewById(R.id.CurrentTimeText);

        // Retrieve the current date
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        IntentFilter filt = new IntentFilter("fromService");
        RADIO_Live.this.registerReceiver(br, filt);

        IntentFilter Podfilt = new IntentFilter("fromServicePod");
        RADIO_Live.this.registerReceiver(PODbr, Podfilt);

        actBroadcast("null", "whatsplaying");

        ArrayList<CharSequence> dateadapterarray = new ArrayList<CharSequence>();

        int ArrayMarker = 0;
        for (int podtest = 1; podtest < 15; podtest++)  {
            MakeDateList(podtest);
            if (dayOfWeek != (1|7)) {
                podFileTest = cMonthName + " " + cDay + ", " + cYear;
                podDatesName[ArrayMarker] = podFileTest;
                String cYearTemp = cYear + "";
                String cMonthTemp = cMonth + "";
                if (cMonth >= 10) {
                } else {
                    cMonthTemp = cMonthTemp.replace("0", "");
                    cMonthTemp = "0" + cMonthTemp;
                }

                if (cDay > 9)   {
                    podDates[ArrayMarker] = (cMonthTemp + "" + cDay + "" + cYearTemp.replace("20", ""));
                }
                if (cDay <= 9)  {
                    podDates[ArrayMarker] = (cMonthTemp + "" + "0" + cDay + "" + cYearTemp.replace("20", ""));
                }
                ArrayMarker++;

            }
            if (dayOfWeek == (1|7) && (ArrayMarker > 0))    {
                ArrayMarker--;
            }
        }

        for (int buildtext = 0; buildtext < 14; buildtext++) {
            dateadapterarray.add(podDatesName[buildtext]);
        }

        fragviewPod = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.podcasts, null);
        Spinner datespinner = (Spinner) fragviewPod.findViewById(R.id.spinnerdate);
        Spinner hourspinner = (Spinner) fragviewPod.findViewById(R.id.spinnerhour);
        //Spinner hourspinner = (Spinner) mViewPager.findViewById(R.id.spinnerhour);

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> dateadapter = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(RADIO_Live.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, dateadapterarray);
        dateadapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> houradapter = new ArrayAdapter<CharSequence>(RADIO_Live.this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, R.array.hour_array);
        houradapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);


        datespinner.setAdapter(dateadapter);
        hourspinner.setAdapter(houradapter);

        // Display the current date under "Today's Date" at the top
        updateCurrentDate();
        datespinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new DateOnItemSelectedListener());
        hourspinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new HourOnItemSelectedListener());

        Button livebutton = (Button) fragviewLive.findViewById(R.id.button_streamstartstop);
        //livebutton.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);

        Button podplaybutton = (Button)fragviewPod.findViewById(R.id.button_pod_play);
        //podplaybutton.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);

    }
```

So to clarify, I have a main.xml which is just the header and the page adapter and then a live.xml and a podcast.xml.

Main.xml:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager         
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/pager"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".RADIO_Live" >

<!--
This title strip will display the currently visible page title, as well as the page
titles for adjacent pages.
-->
<android.support.v4.view.PagerTitleStrip android:id="@+id/pager_title_strip"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:background="#33b5e5"
    android:textColor="#fff"
    android:paddingTop="4dp"
    android:paddingBottom="4dp" />
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Live.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/tab1"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#ffffff"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/tab1.1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="15sp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10sp" android:layout_marginLeft="30sp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30sp" android:textSize="18sp"
        android:text="@string/LiveTabBlurb" />
</LinearLayout>
<Button android:id="@+id/button_streamstartstop"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10sp" android:layout_marginLeft="20sp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20sp" android:textSize="28sp"
    android:textStyle="italic" android:textColor="#FFFFFF" android:text="@string/ListenLiveText" android:onClick="LiveButtonClick" />

<ProgressBar android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="100dp" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/liveProgress" android:paddingTop="30dp"
    android:indeterminateBehavior="cycle" android:indeterminate="true"
    android:visibility="gone">
</ProgressBar>

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/liveProgress"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:visibility="gone" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Podcasts.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/tab2" android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#ffffff">

<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/currentdateDescription"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="5px" android:text="Today's Date:" />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/currentdateDisplay"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="5px" android:text="" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/selecteddateDescription"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="5px" android:text="Selected Date:" />
        <TextView android:id="@+id/selecteddateDisplay"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="5px" android:text="None Selected" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <Spinner android:id="@+id/spinnerdate" android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:prompt="@string/date_prompt" />
    <Spinner android:id="@+id/spinnerhour" android:layout_width="160dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:prompt="@string/hour_prompt" />
</LinearLayout>
<Button android:id="@+id/button_pod_play"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20sp" android:layout_marginRight="20sp"
    android:paddingTop="5sp" android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
    android:textSize="28sp" android:textColor="#FFFFFF" android:textStyle="italic"
    android:text="@string/PlayPodText" android:onClick="PodButtonClick"/>
<SeekBar android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:paddingTop="5dp"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_margin="10dp" android:id="@+id/seekBar" android:max="100"
    android:progress="0" />

<LinearLayout android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/CurrentTimeText"
        android:layout_width="60dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="5px" android:textSize="18px" android:text="0:00" />
    <ProgressBar android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/podProgress" android:paddingTop="10px"
        android:indeterminateBehavior="cycle" android:indeterminate="true"
        android:visibility="gone">
    </ProgressBar>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/TotalTimeText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="5px" android:gravity="right" android:textSize="18px"
        android:text="0:00" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Slightly more background. This app was actually 100% working, but I was using an ugly Android 2.0 days tabbed interface and wanted to update with a nice Holo interface with page view adapter. Not having ever done that before I tried it and I'm getting these problems.

Here's my Fragments code:

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int i) {
        //Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();

        Fragment fragment;
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        switch(i){
            case 0:
                fragment = new fragLive();
                args.putInt(fragLive.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, i + 1);
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new fragPod();
                args.putInt(fragPod.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, i + 1);
                break;
            default:
                fragment = new fragLive();
                args.putInt(fragLive.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, i + 1);
                break;
        }

        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0: return getString(R.string.title_section1).toUpperCase();
            case 1: return getString(R.string.title_section2).toUpperCase();
        }
        return null;
    }
}

/**
 * Two classes for the two layout fragments
 */
public class fragLive extends Fragment {
    public fragLive() {
    }

    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        TextView textView = new TextView(getActivity());
        textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        int test = args.getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER);

        inflater.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        //textView.setText(Integer.toString(args.getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
        fragviewLive = inflater.inflate(R.layout.live, null);
        return fragviewLive;
    }
}

public class fragPod extends Fragment {
    public fragPod() {
    }

    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        TextView textView = new TextView(getActivity());
        textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        Bundle args = getArguments();
        int test = args.getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER);

        inflater.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        //textView.setText(Integer.toString(args.getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
        fragviewPod = inflater.inflate(R.layout.podcasts, null);
        return fragviewPod;
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah if you could only post the relevant code that would be great...

Comment: @tyczj What do you mean? All of the relevant code is there.